# How to change the value/content of my li tag on my navbar when i resized the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good day Sir/Maam..

i just want to ask and get some idea from your opinion that you can give or if possible the exact code :) .
im working on my first website design and i have this problem which is how to change the value or content of my navbar when i full re-sized back my window. 
I dont have any idea how i could solve this.. so plss need help here.. thank you!

this is the output of my sample Project

my navbar in full resized
[image]

my navbar when i resized in max-width 580px and clicked the menu bar
[image]

this is what it looks like when i full resized it again and gives me a hard time to think to turned it to normal.. [image]

sorry for my bad english.. hope to understand my problem and give some idea to solve this.. thanks a lot!

Comment: check position value. 100% sure position issue come. if you have try source code plz make jsfiddle if possible

Comment: You need to post a minimal part of your code, reproducing the issue, or else we can't help.

Comment: no sir.. it stays the same(with no label) even i clicked the menu bar and return it to full screen..

Comment: Are you using CSS media queries? Can we see the CSS then? Or anything?

Comment: yes sir.. i have @media in my css.. actually i already solved my problem and thanks to those who replied even you sir.. big help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to do as exactly a in the pictures **use CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { 

.your_class{
font-size:0px;
}
}
```

change width according to needs. You can also use min-width.

Answer (score 0):

you could look for css media queries:

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  li span { /* on mobile screens span will be hidden try resizing. */
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>icon <span>users</span></li>
  <li>icon <span>profile</span></li>
  <li>icon <span>mail</span></li>
</ul>
```